# Python not starting: IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection

Tags: python

When I try to open Python it gives me an error saying:

`IDLE's subprocess didn't make connection. See the 'startup failure' section of the IDLE doc online`

I am not sure how to get it to start. I am on the most recent version of windows, and on the most recent version of python.

Comment: How are you trying to open it?

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and type python to see if python was installed. If so fix you IDE. If not download and reinstall python.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks. All I needed to do was uninstall random.py.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was solved by deleting random.py

For some reason, it seems python doesn't want you creating a file called random.

Comment: Didn't PythonExplore already give this answer? Please don't duplicate answers.